# RandomForest ROC curve

Tags: r, random-forest, roc

How can I draw the roc curve of this model?

````
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)
training_set <- Boston

set.seed(500)
regressor =randomForest(medv ~ . , data = training_set,ntree=100) 
regressor

regressor

my_prediction = predict(regressor, test_set)
```
````

Comment: library(pROC);roc(...,smooth = TRUE,percent = TRUE,auc = TRUE,ci = TRUE,plot = TRUE)

Comment: can not understand the code?   what is ....?  could you connect it with above code

Comment: @TPArrow: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks. Well I guess the question is not proper for SE-CV then probably will be suspended and removed soon

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your question about plotting the ROC curve from this code, there are at least two issues I can see:

1. At least in the code you provided, there is no `test_set` from which to compute your predicted values in the last line. Perhaps you forgot to include it here, but if not, you definitely need to split the `Boston` data into both a `training` and `test`set at the beginning.
2. More specific to the ROC curve, this plot is used to show the performance of a binary classifier, which from what I can tell from your code, is not your objective as the `medv` variable represents median household value in the `Boston` dataset.  If you are indeed interested in `medv`as your primary outcome, perhaps look into performance metrics for *continuous* outcomes, namely, the loss functions such as MSE or RMSE to start.

If you're still interested in knowing more about ROC and how to plot them with `R`, I've found [Rafael Irizarry's book chapter](https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/introduction-to-machine-learning.html#roc-and-precision-recall-curves) on this helpful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so you say that ROC is not used for regression models, it is used for Classification Models? that was what I wondered about. is it ?

Comment: Question 1 is right. I already have it.

Comment: Thanks, +1. [This is a very helpful answer.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5004/1352)